# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.SurfaceControl.getHandle()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I updated my application to targetSdkVersion = 28 and published to the play store. Then I got very strange crash reports in Frabic. The problem occurs only on Android Pie and I don't have any trace to my code in the crash report, I can't find any null object that incoked by 'android.os.IBinder android.view.SurfaceControl.getHandle()'.

There is a similar question posted on the StackOverflow. I tried to disable proguard but the problem still occurs.

This is the whole crash report listed below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.SurfaceControl.getHandle()' on a null object reference
       at android.os.Parcel.createException + 1956(Parcel.java:1956)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1918(Parcel.java:1918)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1868(Parcel.java:1868)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityPaused + 3993(IActivityManager.java:3993)
       at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.postExecute + 63(PauseActivityItem.java:63)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState + 146(TransactionExecutor.java:146)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute + 70(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1809(ActivityThread.java:1809)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6692(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

======================================================================

```
Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.transferAnimation(SurfaceAnimator.java:231)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.transferAnimation(WindowContainer.java:1136)
    at com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.transferStartingWindow(AppWindowToken.java:1246)
    at com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.transferStartingWindowFromHiddenAboveTokenIfNeeded(AppWindowToken.java:1185)
    at com.android.server.wm.AppWindowContainerController.setVisibility(AppWindowContainerController.java:393)
```

How can I resovle this issue?

Sorry for my bad English, thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this one?